# Autocomplete with json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocomplete

I've been having some trouble getting autocomplete to work specifically with a json file I have been given. I am unsure if this needs to have a php workaround or not, maybe its just a mess of errors in my jquery. However, this is using the autocomplete tool.

Any help at all with this is greatly appreciated.

**The javascript** - Yes the forms are all labeled correctly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.getJSON('data/destination.json', { q: request.term }, function(result) {
                response($.map(result, function(item) {
                return item.value;
            }));
        });
    }
});
```

**The JSON file**

```
{
"destinations": [
    {
        "value": "Oceania and Australia",
        "label": "Australia & South Pacific"
    },
    {
        "value": "Australia",
        "label": "Australia"
    },
    {
        "value": "Brisbane",
        "label": "Brisbane Australia"
    },
    {
        "value": "GoldCoast",
        "label": "GoldCoast-Australia"
    },
    {
        "value": "SunshineCoast",
        "label": "SunshineCoast-Australia"
    },
```

And it goes on like that.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: does  `return item.destinations.value;` work? - sorry.. looking again.. no it wont

Comment: At current the code itself appears not to work at all. The other javascript on the page is working fine except for that, however, this hasn't been working yet which is the annoying part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below. You should apply `$.map` at the destinations of your json data.

```
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.getJSON('data/destination.json', { q: request.term }, function(data) {
            response($.map(data.destinations, function(item) {
            return item.value;
        }));
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a heap, that worked perfectly. Can't believe I missed something like that.